# Compiler not using move c'tor / assignment oper?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Simple question really. What is going on in the following example code that causes it not to compile?

The error occurs at the first line of `main()`:

> "Use of deleted function '`std::__atomic0::...__atomic_base(...)`')"

```
#include <atomic>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    deque<atomic_int> dq;
    Test(){}
};


int main(){
    vector<Test> v = { Test(), Test() };

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling it as c++0x code, in which I understand `atomic` types maybe can't be copied? But either way, the line `vector<Test> v = { Test(), Test() };` should invoke the default *move* constructor/assignment operator of `Test`, which ought to call the *move* constructor/assignment operator of `Test::dq`, avoiding the need to copy any `atomic_int`.

So why won't this compile?

**EDIT**

My compiler will allow me to add non-moveable objects to a container, and then move *the container*. See below:

```
class Test {
public:
    deque<atomic_int> dq;
    Test(){
        dq.resize(10);
    }
};


int main(){
    Test t1;
    Test t2(std::move(t1));

    return 0;
}
```

A move is performed on `t1`, which invokes a move of `t1`'s members, one of which is a `deque`. So a move of each member in `deque` occurs, none of which are of type `atomic_int`

Comment: deque of atomic_int's makes no sense

Comment: Care to elaborate on why a `deque<atomic_int>` makes no sense?

Comment: @AndyMcoy I'm guessing the standard (containers) writers didn't consider the case where a type is assignable but not copy constructible?  Or they specifically excluded those kinds of types.

Comment: @AndyMcoy Another thing, move constructors weren't in the standard until C++11, so maybe your compiler is doing something non-standard?

Comment: because deque isn't atomic so it makes no sense to put an atomic type in there, you'd need to lock on the deque itself

Comment: @paulm Yes, normally that would be true if the deque itself is going to have elements added/removed from seperate threads, but in my case the deque size will remain fixed after initialization, removing any need to lock it before accessing its elements.

Comment: Then why are you using deque? use std::array

Comment: I use a `deque` because I don't know the what the size will be until the containing class' constructor is called. I don't know of any way to declare a `std:array` without specifying a size? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, having a container of only default constructible objects is perfectly legal, provided that you do not use any operation that requires the object to be copyable or movable.

However, `std::initializer_list` allows only `const` access to its elements, meaning that you can't move from them. Hence

```
vector<Test> v = { Test(), Test() };
```

would attempt to *copy* a `Test`, which is not valid because it would attempt to copy the `deque`.

Comment: Would this mean that `vector<atomic_int>` is not allowed even after C++11 if you do push_back's, etc.?

Comment: Objects of type `<atomic_int>` can't be copied, so `vector<atomic_int>` is illegal regardless of how you use the vector, because the vector class will require existing elements to be copied into new memory locations as the vector grows and travels through memory.

Comment: @AndyMcoy Only if I cause the vector to reallocate, right?  Or, at least, it could be implemented that way, I think.

Comment: Yes that's right, however, I believe the vector class just rules out non-copyable types outright. E.g mutexes, references, atomics, none of which can be used to create a vector

Comment: Since C++11: "The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is required that element type is a complete type and meets the requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter requirements." So, I guess it actually depends on how exactly std::vector is implemented in your C++ std library.

Comment: @jschultz410 The standard spells out the requirements on the value type for each operation.

Comment: @AndyMcoy You can do a `vector<atomic_int> f(10);`, and call `pop_back()` or `clear()` on it. That's about it.